# check value in if statement (javascript) from another html file

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, login-script

I am trying to make a page that contains a login form. I got its coding from a website (someone had given that), well in the coding the username and password is given for compare (which can be seen by anyone, who opens the html codes), that's why i want that how the value of username and password can be compared in java-script from an external txt file or html file.
Kindly see the coding in order to better understand my problem. In coding "ABC" and "123" are username and password.

```
<body>
  <h1 style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;text-align="center";font-size:20pt;
color:#00FF00;>
Simple Login Page
  </h1>
      <form name="login">
          Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
          Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
          <input type="button" onClick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
          <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
      </form>
      <script language="javascript">
      function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
      {
          /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
          if(form.userid.value = "ABC" && form.pswrd.value == "123")
          {
              window.open('target.html')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
          }
          else
          {
              alert("Error Password or Username")/*displays error message*/
          }
      }
      </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: From a security perspective you shouldn't be storing username/password in an html/text file. Are you not using a database of some sort?

Comment: use ajax to get the text file(.json) and compare the value?

Comment: You can't expect to securely do password checks on the client in this way.  If your script can download a username/password file for checking, so can anyone else, and they can then see what the password is.  Passwords need to stay on the server, but even then not in plain text - they should be salted and hashed.

Answer (score 0):

Technicly, you can load by AJAX a txt/xml or json file and read the data from that.

However, **I strongly recommend** that you make the user/password check on the **server side** as if you do it in javascript, it won't be secure at all as anyone could read them in less than 5 seconds !!!

Comment: Thanks a lot brother, means that goes for a complex coding,,,,, and i should totally avoid using this code...